# Unity Fix NavMeshAgent Auto Rotate 90 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, game-development

I am currently using a Taxi model from as an enemy with AI that will drive to different waypoints. Whenever the car moves to a waypoint it auto rotates 90 degrees to the right, right away but keeps moving from waypoint to waypoint.

How do I fix a NavMeshAgent that auto turns 90 degrees when moving to a waypoint? The commented out code fixes the auto rotate but does not rotate enough when moving to the waypoint upon setDestination.

The uncommented code first rotates 90 degrees and then rotates a little after each waypoint (from the 90 degree position).  (Unity API script from Vector3.RotateTowards)

_agent.UpdateRotation = false , stops initial rotation but I then have to control rotation manually (which I am having a hard time with)

### [image: screenshot]

```
 private void Start()
    {
        _agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
         // Almost works doesn't rotate enough
        //_agent.updateRotation = false;
        _isStopped = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Almost works, doesn't rotate enough
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, (_angleToRotate) * 8, 0), 1f);

        //Rotates but turns 90 degrees first
        Vector3 targetDirection = _wayPoints[_currentWayPoint].transform.position - transform.position;
        float singleStep = _speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, newDirection, Color.red);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);

        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case AIState.NonAlert:
                //Debug.Log("Not Alert...");

                if (_isStopped == true)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_wayPoints.Count > 0)
                    {
                        _agent.SetDestination(_wayPoints[_currentWayPoint].transform.position);

                        //Gets distance between two Vector3s
                        float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(_wayPoints[_currentWayPoint].transform.position, transform.position);

                        if (distanceToWayPoint < 1.0f)
                        {
                            _currentWayPoint++;

                            //Almost works, doesnt rotate enough
                            //_angleToRotate = Vector3.SignedAngle(transform.position, _wayPoints[_currentWayPoint].transform.position, Vector3.up);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

---

Comment: can you share the video, please? I just want to check that the car is moving in the direction of the way point that is in the picture.

Comment: IS the redline is a ray that is being drawn by ```Debug.DrawRay()```  or something else?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the waypoint to face the way you want

Comment: @Ankit Yes the car is moving in the direction of the way point in the picture (same direction as x-axis), the redline is just what I drew on the snapshot

Comment: @BugFinder I rotated it -90 degrees but it still points down +90 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the taxi model itself has an 90° offset.
You can change that with creating a prefab for the taxi model with an empty gameobject as parent and give the taxi the needed 90° offset on the prefab. After that you use the parent object for movement and rotation

Or

Change the direction of the model in blender or any other 3d modeling tool

Comment: Can you list out in more detail the steps involved in your answer? I tried changing the rotation in blender -90 and +90 but it still rotates +90 when setDestination is called.

For the other fix first I would create empty > turn its rotation on the y to -90 > add nav mesh agent to empty > add enemy AI script to empty > remove nav mesh agent and enemy AI script from Taxi gameobject correct?

Comment: The steps I described helped me, I had to set the parent empty gameobject to -270 and put the nav mesh agent and script on the empty object , then added the Taxi gameobject to the empty gameobject as a child